# React Native - Scrollview - Apply a zoom using a method/function not pinch

Tags: react-native, scrollview, zooming

As the `zoomScale` parameter does not seem to affect the initial zoom level, I would like to set a zoom on my `ScrollView` using a method/function.

I found that via the `ScrollView` reference, I can get the responder and then apply *scrollResponderZoomTo* but it's iOS only.

Is there a way to manipulate the zoom of a `ScrollView` by another way than the pinch gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it's possible to use the function `scrollResponderZoomTo` on the responder of the `ScrollView` via the reference of the component :

```
...
<ScrollView
   ref={this.scrollViewRef}
...
```

And a call like this :

```
this.scrollViewRef.current?.getScrollResponder().scrollResponderZoomTo({
    x: viewContentOffsetX || 0,
    y: viewContentOffsetY || 0,
    width: widthOfTheVisiblePart,
    height: heightOfTheVisiblePart,
    animated: false})
```

Up to a function to calculate the visible part based on the expected zoom value